# Data imputation for a dataset where all values are 1 or N/A

Tags: data-imputation

I have a dataset which contains relations between jobs and skills required for these jobs. It is a matrix with value 1 if a skill is required for a job, and N/A otherwise. N/A instead of zero because I believe that the dataset is not complete, e.g. a job description might include a skill of SQL Server, but not a skill of SQL, though knowledge of SQL is crucial for any work related to SQL Server.
To be able to analyze the data better (I want to do cluster analysis on jobs) I want to replace N/A values with values between 0 and 1, depending on a set of skills which are known to be required for the job.
What are techniques which can be used for this task?